# What is incorrect with this HOOK_node_presave method ?? Trying to modify a FAPI textfield

Tags: 7, nodes, forms, hooks

```
/*
 * Implements hook_node_presave()
 */

function custom_kca_node_presave($node) {
    drupal_set_message('DEBUG: PRESAVE Called');
    if ($node->type === 'product') {
        $node->field_product_short['und'][] = 'test';
    }
}
```

I created a custom textfield called *field_product_short* on the *product* Content Type.

A krumo check on $node after saving reveals $node->field_product_short to have the following:

```
field_product_short (Array, 1 element)
    und (Array, 1 element)
        0 (Array, 1 element)
            value (String, 1 characters ) t | (Callback) t();
```

?!? I'm setting it to a string in my HOOK. Why is it setting it to a value only of 't' with a callback t(); method? Shouldn't it just be reading:

```
field_product_short (Array, 1 element)
    und (Array, 1 element)
        0 (Array, 1 element)
            (String, 4 characters ) test
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your structure is wrong, you are missing the 'value' part. Something like this should work:

```
$node->field_product_short['und'][0]['value'] = 'test';
```

I'd recommend to explicitly use [0] instead of [], the first always writes the first field value while the second appends a new one (which is 0 if it is the first). Within it are the actual values of the field, which is, in case of a text field the mentioned 'value'. A term refernence would be tid, a node reference nid and so on.

The reason you are getting 't' is because the field structure is now a string where Drupal expects an array. Example:

```
$string = 'abc';
echo $string['value'];
```

This prints 'a', because only integers are supported when accessing strings like this which means 'value' is casted to a 0 and the first character of the $string is 'a'. Welcome to the strange world of PHP.

And another hint. The callback stuff is there because there also exists a function 't'. krumo doesn't know if something is a callback or not (as this is not possible to know in PHP), it simply checks if a function with the same name exists.

Comment: could this be applied when other node field value should be placed instead of 'test'. ex: `$node->field_product_short['und'][0]['value'] = $node->field_some_other_field['und'][0]['value'];`. Can we have access to $node->field_some_other_field here?